# ASP MVC3 and Telerik DatePicker control blocking year/month pick after Ajax action

Tags: ajax, telerik, datepicker, asp.net-mvc

So I'm in big trouble here.

```
<%: Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("dataWprowadzeniaOd").ShowButton(true)%> - 
<%:Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("dataWprowadzeniaDo").ShowButton(true) %>
```

I have these two nice DatePickers, a list and some filtering options, all on Ajax. Now when Ajax action occurs (like filtering, refreshing table, changing pages) these two cute little things block in a way user is not able to change month and year there.

Here's beginning of table code:

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
.Name("Main")
.DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(p => p.DepozytID))
.Localizable("pl-PL")
.Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true).PageSize(20))
```

I've tried putting:

```
$('#dataWprowadzeniaOd').tDatePicker({ format: 'yyyy-MM-dd', minValue: new Date(1899, 11, 31), 
maxValue: new Date(2100, 0, 1) });
$('#dataWprowadzeniaDo').tDatePicker({ format: 'yyyy-MM-dd', minValue: new Date(1899, 11, 31), 
maxValue: new Date(2100, 0, 1) });
```

at the end of every callback/ajax function, but it removes month/year bar from calendar so I can't check if it works o.O

Tried this:

```
$('#dataWprowadzeniaOd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#dataWprowadzeniaOd').attr('disabled', '');
```

too, but no effect.

```
    function filtruj() {
        var newurl = '<%: Url.Content("~/RejestrDepozytow/ListaDepozytow") %>';
        var filtr = {};

        filtr.typStatusu = $("#typStatusu").val();
        filtr.rodzajDepozytuID = $("#rodzajDepozytuID").val();
        filtr.dataWprowadzeniaOd = $("#dataWprowadzeniaOd").val();
        filtr.dataWprowadzeniaDo = $("#dataWprowadzeniaDo").val();
        filtr.podmiotSkladajacyID = $("#podmiotSkladajacyID").val();
        filtr.podmiot = $("#podmiot").val();
        filtr.sygnaturaSprawy = $("#sygnaturaSprawy").val();
        filtr.barcode = $("#barcode").val();
        filtr.numerLp = $("#numerLp").val();
        filtr.numerRok = $("#numerRok").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: newurl,
            data: filtr,
            success: function (dane) {
                $("#gridDepozytow").html(dane);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's method used just before datepicker getting blocked.

Comment: I can't see anything in what you entered that would cause blocking. Maybe you could list the ajax code that occasions the blocking.

Comment: It's Telerik control default behaviour. But it only happens when Ajax call was used beforehand.